# If I lose my papers/passport in the US, what police station should I report it to?

Tags: usa, passports, paperwork

If I lose my ID papers, credit cards or passport in the US, in order to report the loss, do I have to go to a specific type of police station (city, transit, state police), or could I just go to any of them, the closest police station when I notice I lost them?

**EDIT** : It looks like it all depends on the precise area I lost my papers. So if I notice the loss after a while - and as I lost them, I don't know where they are - how could I determine the precise area I lost them? Say I visit city A on day 1, city B on day 2, I notice on day 2 I lost them, maybe in city A, do I have to go back to city A?

As @Relaxed said, the French consulate requires a police report as a proof of loss/robbery. It sounds also natural - in France, at least - that police reports of loss/robbery are the standard proof to show to insurances for claims.

Comment: Why would you report it to the police at all? It would never occur to me to do so outside the US, I'd just head straight for the nearest consulate.

Comment: @Dave French consulates (maybe others too but I think that Vince, like myself, is a French citizen) generally expect a police report if your ID was stolen. There are probably ways around that requirement, especially if you are in a country where the police is not particularly helpful, but in principle [that's the first thing you are supposed to do](http://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/fr/vivre-a-l-etranger/en-cas-de-difficulte-a-l-etranger/article/vol-et-perte-de-documents-a-l).

Comment: @Relaxed Presumably, the French consulate could help you figure out where to file the police report if you don't know, right? So if you're unsure, you still might go to the consulate first.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As with all police matters, it is probably best to go to the police station that covers the smallest area that you are within.

- If you lost your papers in a train station (large enough to have its own transit police), go to the transit police.
- If you lost your papers in a city, go to the city police.
- If you lost your papers outside a city, go to the state police.

If you don't know whether you are within a city or not, ask somebody. In large metro areas there may be multiple city police agencies (for example, if you're in northeast Dallas, you might need to visit the Plano Police).

Comment: Note that some places have county police also.  You also may find things like our <city name> metropolitan police--one department that covers not only the city but nearby developed areas also.

Comment: Outside of a city, you might also want to go to the sheriff, depending on the county. Most counties will have a county police or a sheriff, but that isn't always the case.

Answer (score 11):

The United States has a very complicated law enforcement system, it's often difficult to tell the difference between police and private security. For example, New York City transit police are real police. The ones minding the trains in many smaller cities are not, yet they have uniforms, radios, guns etc.

However, any law enforcement officer will know who is responsible for what in their area. If you do lose your papers just call the number on any police car you see driving by and ask. If he's stopped, walk up to the car and ask - they might take your report on the spot. You can also call 9-1-1 and ask for the non-emergency phone number (don't start on the story, just ask for the regular police phone number).

Comment: Note to answer editors: Phone books? How quaint. Becoming increasingly harder to find in many places. 9-1-1 doesn't mind if you ask for the regular number and then get off the line, same reason. And don't change other people's words. If you disagree, leave a comment or an answer of your own.

Comment: I did not edit (and in fact upvoted) your answer but I was a bit surprised by this too. Is there by any chance any official guidance on whether you should call 911 in this situation? I think that in Europe, most countries try to publicize non-emergency numbers and discourage people from calling 112.

Comment: @Relaxed it was someone else who substantially rephrased what I said. I've done it a few times and was simply told the regular number. One time, the same person answered the regular phone 5 seconds later and had absolutely nothing to say about it. Of course, try other methods first but if my passport has been stolen and the embassy closes in an hour.....

Comment: Yes, I saw that and completely understand your reaction. I did not mean to justify the edit but I was just wondering.

Comment: In the UK we have directory enquiry services, for example one can access [that provided by BT](http://www.bt118500.com/) by dialling `118500`—it would be preferable to call such a service in order to discover a local police non-emergency number than to dial `999` or (the [EU-wide emergency number](http://www.eena.org/)) `112`; that said, there is now a [UK-wide non-emergency police number](http://www.police.uk/contact/101/): `101`.  Does the US not have similar directory enquiry services, or standardised non-emergency police numbers?

Comment: It looks like [3-1-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-1-1) and [4-1-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4-1-1) would be the US equivalents for non-emergency police and directory enquiry services, respectively.

Comment: @Relaxed It's fairly standard advice in the US that it's acceptable to call 911 and *immediately* say "this is not an emergency," and they'll redirect you. It's not *ideal* to call 911 in that situation, but they don't mind, and in some places it's the main way to report non-emergency things.

Comment: One should not call 9-1-1 for situations that are not urgent emergencies.

Comment: @eggyal 4-1-1 is directory service, but that mostly helps if you already know the police department name. 3-1-1 is only in some cities (by no means nationwide).

Comment: Interestingly enough, 911 is often handled by the same people as the non-emergency number. It merely sets the priority of the call.

For example, I've called about non-emergencies before and been put on hold for a 911 call. 

This may not be the case everywhere though.

Comment: I've never heard this. If it's not an emergency, you have enough time to look up the non-emergency number online.

Comment: There is no such thing as the New York City Transit Police.  That agency was abolished in 1995 and rolled into the New York Police Department.  The police officers you see in the New York City subway, therefore are NYPD officers, the same as on the street.

Comment: @phoog didn't know that. There is still the US Park Police, various railroad police etc. with limited jurisdictions.

Comment: There's even an MTA police, which is the railroad police for the MTA's commuter railroads.  There used to be the NYC Housing Police, but that agency was also merged into the NYPD in 1995.  NYC Parks Enforcement officers are peace officers, not police officers, and I can't think of any other law enforcement agencies operating in the city, but I am sure there are more.

Comment: I know I've called 911 a couple times.  In every instance the very first thing *they* ask is "Emergency or Non-Emergency?"  Not sure if this is true throughout the country or not.

Comment: @paul - Contacting the right source for assistance on the first call by looking up the non-emergency number makes your already good suggestion better. It gets the person to the right non-emergency number in one call and without going through the emergency number (911) first. I believe my edit made your post substantively better, my apologies if I ruffled your feathers. I do see your point about phone books, the point was to use resources other than 911 to find the non-emergency number first. http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/editing

Comment: @Freiheit: I did say call the number printed on any police car he sees. The person asking the question appears to be french, and thus the various processes a local resident would be fully aware of are not easily available. Googling "NYC Police" won't help you if you are across the river in New Jersey, yet most tourists would consider Ellis Island to be in New York.

Comment: Just searching Google for "police" on your mobile with location enabled will usually bring up the right department, unless you're in one of those corner cases like standing on a state line. As for 911, you can't really use it for non-emergencies here; it's a statewide call center.

Answer (score 7):

It depends a bit on where you are, as there are a number of policing units from state police to country sheriffs to city police to university police to transit police.  But ultimately, they can all file a report on the lost documents for you to present to your embassy.

On a general basis, if you don't know exactly where you lost them, then you would go to the city / metropolitan police for that town. They have the broadest jurisdiction and are the most likely place that lost documents would be turned in. And more specialized police (transit police, university police, etc) would have access to their database, should the lost documents be turned in to their office.

If you are certain you lost it on a train/bus or on a campus, then you could report the loss to those specific police.  But otherwise use the main police force for the city.

If by chance you think you left it behind at a roadside truck stop or some other such place in rural areas, then either the local county sheriff (if you know approximately where) or the state police if you have been traveling and could have left it multiple places.

Ultimately notifying your embassy is the primary first step.